# How can I use jquery to check if two attributes have the same value?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a jquery selector that will select objects that have the same value for two of their attributes.

Something like this:

```
$('div[attr1=attr2]')
```

Given:

```
<div attr1="foo" attr2="bar">A</div>
<div attr1="bar" attr2="bar">B</div>
<div attr1="foo" attr2="bar">C</div>
<div attr1="foo" attr2="foo">D</div>
```

I want it to return links to the B and D divs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [custom selectors with arguments](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html).

```
$('div:attrEqual(attr1 attr2)')
```

You define the custom selector like this:

```
$.expr[':'].attrEqual = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
  var attrs = meta[3].split(" ");
  return $(obj).attr(attrs[1]) == $(obj).attr(attrs[0]);
};
```

For performance, add `[attr1][attr2]` to the selector so that the native DOM filters out nodes that don't have both attributes.

Comment: I think this is exactly what he wanted.

Comment: Very sexy. Im not sure if i fully get it: Is this gonna work regardless of the name of the attr?

Comment: hm, odd, meo is right, doesn't seem to work, or are we just using it wrong?

Comment: the equalAttr name is the culprit. Sorry, did this off the top of my head. Rename `equalAttr` to `attrEqual` and it works. Answer edited to reflect that. Also, embedded quotes are not needed around the attribute names in the selector.

Answer (score 5):

I think the attribute selector only allows you to compare with a constant value. But you can use the `.filter()` function to do the comparison:

```
$('div[attr1][attr2]').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).attr('attr1') == $(this).attr('attr2');
})
```

Comment: you need to remove the leading `$('` in your example in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do the trick ([The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQbHu/)):

```
function GetWithSameAttributes (parID)
{
    var output = new Array();

    $('#'+parID).children().each(function ()
    {
        if ($(this).is('[attr1="'+$(this).attr('attr2')+'"]'))
            output.push($(this).html());
    });
   return output;
}

$(function ()
{
    for (val in GetWithSameAttributes('Items'))
        document.writeln(val + ' has the same attributes<BR/>');
});
```

with the html something like:

```
<div id="Items">
    <div attr1="foo" attr2="bar">A</div>
    <div attr1="bar" attr2="bar">B</div>
    <div attr1="foo" attr2="bar">C</div>
    <div attr1="foo" attr2="foo">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right, you want to know if any attribute has the same value, regardless of its name. You could do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zuwZh/2/

```
$("div").filter(function(){
var attributes = this.attributes,
    i = attributes.length,
    attrValues = [],
    $that = $(this);
    if(i !== 1) {
     while( i-- ) {
        var attr = attributes[i];
        attrValues.push(attr.value);
     }
    attrValues = attrValues.sort();
    if(attrValues[0] === attrValues[1]) {
        return $that; //only checks between two attributes, but you could extend that
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use a double equals sign (==) to check for equality in an statement. single equals(=) is for assignment.
So if($('div[attr1] == div[attr2]') { do something });

Comment: The attribute equals selector in jQuery uses only one equals sign. See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: yes, the selector uses one equals sign, but the question seems to indicate that it is looking for equality checking between the values of multiple attributes. Maybe I am misreading the documentation, but it appears the single equals is used to associate the attribute with its value, not equality checking between two values.